# Can't move 2012r2 server to different Azure region due to Trusted Root Certs are not present

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012-r2

When using Azure Resource Mover moving a 2012r2 standalone server to a differernt region all the supporting resources have been moved successfully except for the vm itself.

Error generated: Ensure the trusted root certificates are present on the machine https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn265983.aspx

I do see the certs present in the MMC: [2012r2_Certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eWNK.png)

[Referenced this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn265983.aspx) but unable to resolve the issue. any insight would be appreciated how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error generated: Ensure the trusted root certificates are present on
> the machine.

This error usually occurs if the trusted root certificates are not present on the machine and if the certificates are not installed properly and located into different location. Try to regenerate the certificates and the certificates should be in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. Install the latest Windows updates on the VM. This will ensure that all the trusted root certificates are on the machine.

To move 2012 r2 server to different Azure region using Azure Resource Mover make use of below steps:

In Azure resource mover select source and destination region and click on virtual machine:

[image]

[image]

Add dependencies, dependencies are automatically validated in the background when you add the resources.

[image]

Click on ***Prepare***. This will move the VMs, the VM resource group must be present in the target region. It will revalidate all the resources are there if not, it will automatically add and start preparation.

[image]

Now, click on ***initiate*** this will point resources and it will get moved from source region to target region.

Then click on ***commit*** once commit is completed status of resources will be changed as source region to target region:

[image]

If still issue persists, you can make use of Azure Site Recovery or manual migration using Azure Backup and Restore. These methods might offer different approaches to handle the certificate-related issues.

***Reference***:

[Move Azure VMs across regions with Azure Resource Mover | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-mover/tutorial-move-region-virtual-machines)